# Used v16.0~rc1 when the activation of Mumbai on block #3,268,609

Tags: node, protocol, upgrade, archive-node

When the protocol was changed to Mumbai, I still used v16.0~rc1 and got errors such below

```
Mar 30 01:40:31.395 - validation: initializing protocol PtMumbaiiFFE...
Mar 30 01:40:31.519 - validator.block: block BMJzr4j2fUNXh4tb1npQZNikgswhN2RJiZp6DoMRbRT6NGKbVnC validated
Mar 30 01:40:31.519 - validator.block:   Request pushed on 2023-03-29T16:40:21.877-00:00, treated in 21.384ms, completed in 9.621s
Mar 30 01:40:31.712 - node.store: the protocol table was updated: protocol PtMumbaiiFFE (level 16) was
Mar 30 01:40:31.712 - node.store:   activated on block BMJzr4j2fUNXh4tb1npQZNikgswhN2RJiZp6DoMRbRT6NGKbVnC
Mar 30 01:40:31.712 - node.store:   (level 3268608)
Mar 30 01:40:31.733 - validator.chain: Update current head to BMJzr4j2fUNXh4tb1npQZNikgswhN2RJiZp6DoMRbRT6NGKbVnC
Mar 30 01:40:31.733 - validator.chain:   (level 3268608, timestamp 2023-03-29T16:39:59-00:00, fitness
Mar 30 01:40:31.733 - validator.chain:   02::0031e000::::ffffffff::00000000), changing branch
Mar 30 01:40:37.372 - validator.block: precheck of block BM1QtXxQ9AauM4fhmSE3b7Y6M1tAYgoKFQXhNVeGrvxSnZpe9tm failed,
Mar 30 01:40:37.372 - validator.block:   Request pushed on 2023-03-29T16:40:37.240-00:00, treated in 1.435ms, completed in 130ms:
Mar 30 01:40:37.372 - validator.block:   Invalid block BM1QtXxQ9Aau
Mar 30 01:40:37.372 - validator.block:     Failed to validate the economic-protocol content of the block. More details in the trace.
Failed to send event: Error:
                        Lwt.Resolution_loop.Canceled

Mar 30 01:40:37.383 - validator.peer: worker crashed [validator-peer]:
Mar 30 01:40:37.383 - validator.peer:   Error:
Mar 30 01:40:37.383 - validator.peer:     Invalid block BM1QtXxQ9Aau
Mar 30 01:40:37.383 - validator.peer:       Failed to validate the economic-protocol content of the block. More details in the trace.,
Mar 30 01:40:37.383 - validator.peer:     trace:
Mar 30 01:40:37.383 - validator.peer:     Inconsistent hash:
Mar 30 01:40:37.383 - validator.peer:       got: CoW7od7xUKYhnZGpyFGbEMLjzngyAQcTEzRgqYAJ2kfcNzASuLeN
Mar 30 01:40:37.383 - validator.peer:       expected: CoVgwBPqj4LndGGXKPMj2PyBLodG1kF7A92MZ36WHQYwUV874WZX
Mar 30 01:40:37.383 - validator.peer:       Invalid block BM1QtXxQ9Aau
Mar 30 01:40:37.383 - validator.peer:         Failed to validate the economic-protocol content of the block. More details in the trace.
Mar 30 01:40:37.383 - validator.peer: 
Mar 30 01:40:37.383 - validator.chain: disconnection of idrWmqahUtkPoXzKeKkuhpMw9sdpN5
Mar 30 01:40:37.389 - validator.block: precheck of block BM1QtXxQ9AauM4fhmSE3b7Y6M1tAYgoKFQXhNVeGrvxSnZpe9tm failed,
Mar 30 01:40:37.389 - validator.block:   Request pushed on 2023-03-29T16:40:37.240-00:00, treated in 142ms, completed in 6.867ms:
Mar 30 01:40:37.389 - validator.block:   Invalid block BM1QtXxQ9Aau
Mar 30 01:40:37.389 - validator.block:     Failed to validate the economic-protocol content of the block. More details in the trace.
Failed to send event: Error:
                        Lwt.Resolution_loop.Canceled
:
```

After restarting my node, got errors repeatedly such below

```
Mar 31 20:41:56.439 - validator.block: precheck of block BM1QtXxQ9AauM4fhmSE3b7Y6M1tAYgoKFQXhNVeGrvxSnZpe9tm failed,
Mar 31 20:41:56.439 - validator.block:   Request pushed on 2023-03-31T11:41:56.408-00:00, treated in 788us, completed in 29.346ms:
Mar 31 20:41:56.439 - validator.block:   Missing protocol (PtMumbaiiFFE) when validating the block BM1QtXxQ9Aau.
:
```

Maybe noticed that `PtMumbaiiFFE` is not the current protocol name of Mumbai: `PtMumbai2Tms` is correct

Do you know the possible way to fix my node?

I don't configure special settings except for `history_mode=archive`.
Because of this, I don't want to recreate a node by importing a snapshot if I can

### Tried

I tried `./octez-admin-client inject protocol PtMumbaiiFFE` using the directory in `store/protocols/` and it succeeded, but it didn't change the error

Answer (score 2):

You should upgrade to v16.1.

v16.0-rc1 contains the old protocol `Mumbaii` which was replaced by `Mumbai2` with an user-activated protocol override.

You will probably be able to restore your node without recreating the storage, but if you need to, there are archive tarballs available at https://xtz-shots.io

Comment: Just after getting this error, I upgraded my node to v16.1 but seemed to be late.
I wonder if there is no way to fix my node other than to recreate or fetch it...